# Vertical scrolling inside GridView group of items in WinRT XAML

Tags: windows, xaml, gridview, windows-runtime, vertical-scrolling

I am using GridView for displaying groups of different sets of items in a WinRT XAML app. Everything works well, except that the ItemsPanelTemplate uses a wrapping grid which stacks my items vertically when it's out of space.

So, I tried to use StackPanel, like this:

```
<GroupStyle.Panel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Visibility="Visible" />
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</GroupStyle.Panel>
```

The items are stacked vertically, and that's great, but the problem is now that I can't scroll them, and they don't fit on the screen. So I tried enabling vertical scrolling:

```
<GroupStyle.Panel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Visibility="Visible" 
                    ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
                    ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Enabled"/>
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</GroupStyle.Panel>
```

But that doesn't work.
Any suggestions how to accomplish vertical scrolling inside GridView group?

**EDIT 1:**

I have also tried this:

```
<GroupStyle.Panel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
                      HorizontalScrollMode="Disabled" 
                      ZoomMode="Disabled" 
                      VerticalScrollMode="Enabled">
              <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Visibility="Visible" />
         </ScrollViewer>
     </ItemsPanelTemplate>
 </GroupStyle.Panel>
```

This breaks the debugger as the ItemsPanelTemplate needs a panel as a child.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

OK, I finally solved it! To whom it may concern:

```
<GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="GroupItem">
        <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="GroupItem">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" Grid.Row="0"/>
                    <ItemsControl x:Name="ItemsControl2" ItemsSource="{Binding GroupItems}" Grid.Row="1">
                        <ItemsControl.Template>
                        <ControlTemplate>
                            <ScrollViewer x:Name="ScrollViewer" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"                                                  VerticalScrollMode="Enabled" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"                                                  HorizontalScrollMode="Disabled">
                            <ItemsPresenter />
                            </ScrollViewer>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl.Template>
                    </ItemsControl>
                </Grid>
           </ControlTemplate>
       </Setter.Value>
       </Setter>
   </Style>
</GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
```

It's important that you use the Grid to make sure that the ScrollViewer scales correctly.

Comment: How come your scrollviewer is scaling correctly! I put a ListView with horizontal flow inside a grid. My whole ListView scrolls rather than individual columns.

Comment: Good, yes. This is what you have to do. Basically dock your scrollviewer in a grid so its height is set and you can scroll inside it.

Comment: XamlCompiler warning WMC1500: 'ContainerStyle' is deprecated: ContainerStyle may be altered or unavailable for releases after Windows 8.1, and is not supported for ItemsControl.GroupStyle.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I also need to set the `MaxHeight` of the `Grid` in order to make the scroll work.

Answer (score 2):

What about this?

It renders elements like this:
Item 1    Item 2
Item 3    Item 4

```
<ListView Width="200">
    <ListBoxItem>
        <TextBlock>Item 1</TextBlock>
    </ListBoxItem>
    <ListBoxItem>
        <TextBlock>Item 2</TextBlock>
    </ListBoxItem>
    <ListBoxItem>
        <TextBlock>Item 3</TextBlock>
    </ListBoxItem>
    <ListBoxItem>
        <TextBlock>Item 4</TextBlock>
    </ListBoxItem>
    <ListView.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapGrid Orientation="Horizontal"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemsPanel>
</ListView>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would place your elements inside a scroll viewer directly. Like this:

```
<GroupStyle.Panel>
 <ItemsPanelTemplate>
      <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" HorizontalScrollMode="Disabled" ZoomMode="Disabled" VerticalScrollMode="Enabled">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Visibility="Visible" />
      </ScrollViewer>
 </ItemsPanelTemplate>
```

I hope this helps,
Lance

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have tried this too. This breaks the debugger, as ItemsPanelTemplate needs a panel as a child.

Comment: What if you place an additional buffer grid or stackpanel to hold the scrollviewer. This should satisfy the template and still look the same to the user. ItemsPanelTemplate > Stackpanel >Scrollviewer > Stackpanel

Comment: @LanceMcCarthy That won't work either. You'll still get debugger break.

Answer (score 0):

You may also wants to set the ZoomMode of the ScrollViewer to Disabled :)

Regards