# Why does my grid not scroll vertically

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-phone-8

My grid does not scroll vertically even when I change the orientation in my wrapgrid to vertical or horizontal. However in horizontal my items are arranged vertically and I do get the scroll bar to scroll but when I use the scroll bar it does not work vertically.

```
 <Grid Grid.Row="2" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="120,0,0,0">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBlock FontSize="26" Text="You are assigned to the following wards, please select one to continue:"/>
        <GridView Name="WardGridView" ItemsSource="{Binding 
        Source={StaticResource WardGridViewCollectionViewSource}}" 
              SelectionMode="None" 
              IsItemClickEnabled="True" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
              ItemClick="WardGridView_ItemClick" Grid.Row="1" >
            <GridView.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <WrapGrid Margin="0,0,0,10" Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </GridView.ItemsPanel>
            <GridView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid Width="1000" Height="500" Background="#DBDBDB">
                        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="Black" FontFamily="Segoe UI" Text="{Binding message}" FontSize="20" />
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </GridView.ItemTemplate>
        </GridView>
    </Grid>
```

what do I need to change in my code to allow my items to scroll vertically?

Comment: `GridView` in WPF is not a control.  Is this a WPF question or a Windows Phone question?  Please remove whichever tag does not apply.

Comment: [Possible duplicate of this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11135480/vertical-scrolling-inside-gridview-group-of-items-in-winrt-xaml)?

Comment: I don't think you could use `GridView` for a WP application.

Answer (score 3):

Change the RowDefinition to this:

```
  <!-- Row where the GridView is shown -->
  <RowDefinition Height="*" />
```